# Add excel worksheet to email using share-intent using bytestream

Tags: java, android, excel, android-intent

I try to create and send an excel sheet in android/java using the following code, but i can't complete the code for the correct syntax on adding the ByteArrayDataSource to the intent:

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your excel sheet");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello! I am sending the excel sheet");

    Workbook xlsFile = new HSSFWorkbook();
    CreationHelper helper = xlsFile.getCreationHelper();
    Sheet sheet1 = xlsFile.createSheet("New worksheet");

    /* fill excel sheet */

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        xlsFile.write(bos); // write excel data to a byte array
        DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bos.toByteArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        bos.close();
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ??? /* how to add the ByteArrayDataSource here?? */);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send via"));
```

How can i attach the excel sheet without storing it on sdcard?

Thank you!

Best regards,
Juergen

Update:

I have it done by storing to sdcard first:

```
                    try {
                        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        File file = new File(sdCard, "file.xls");
                        file.createNewFile();

                        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        xlsFile.write(bos);
                        fo.write(bos.toByteArray());
                        bos.close();
                        fo.flush();
                        fo.close();

                        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///" + file.getPath()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

If someone knows a way to do it without storing it, please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I try to create and send an excel sheet in android/java using the following code

First, you have the wrong MIME type, as `text/plain` is not the MIME type for an Excel spreadsheet.

Second, you can [use either `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`, not both](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND).

> How can i attach the excel sheet without storing it on sdcard?

Store it on internal storage and [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve it to the third-party app.

Comment: The text/plain is for the body of the email.
So i can't add the excel sheet without storing it first?

Comment: @Juwei: "The text/plain is for the body of the email" -- quoting the docs: "Input: getType() is the MIME type of the data being sent. get*Extra can have either a EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent. If using EXTRA_TEXT, the MIME type should be "text/plain"; otherwise it should be the MIME type of the data in EXTRA_STREAM." You cannot use both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM`. Choose one. Then, set the MIME type as documented.

Comment: @Juwei: "So i can't add the excel sheet without storing it first?" -- you may not have heap space to do anything else, as Excel files can be large. It should be possible to create a `ContentProvider` that serves from heap space, though I have never tried this.

Comment: I have done it by storing to sdcard first. See my updated request. If someone knows a way to do it without storing it, please let me know! Thanks!